# Make multiple POST requests to a URL concurrently in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm using Django and Django Rest Framework. Inside my `urls.py`, I've defined the following endpoint `/payments/`. It supports `POST` requests.

Background info: Not long ago, we had a user send multiple requests to this server concurrently triggering a race condition and therefore stealing money.

Question:

1. How can I write a test to send 100-1000 requests to this URL API endpoint?

This is how I currently send POST "test" requests in my test file:

```py
class PaymentViewTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(PaymentViewTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.profile)

    def test_post_create_payment(self):
        amount = 1000
        request_data = {
            'amount': amount,
        }
        res = self.client.post(
            '/payment/',
            ujson.dumps(request_data),
            content_type='application/json',
            secure=True
        )
```

However, I would like to trigger this `POST` request 1000, **exactly** at the same time.

Comment: If you mean *asynchronously*, then this is relatively  easily to accomplish with [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html). If you require that the requests run in *parallel*, then this becomes much more complicated.  You can start with [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), where you can create a [group](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) of requests that run in parallel.

Comment: @CalebGoodman With *asynchronously*, does that mean that the POST request will be submitted at the same time exactly? I would like to stay away from implementing Celery in the tests and starting different workers to run the same POST request.

Comment: no, not necessarily.  But *race conditions* will occur if your app isn't prepared for them.

Comment: @CalebGoodman Just a quick question, how do you do to avoid hackers from doing this? We are using `@transaction.atomic()` and `select_for_update(nowait=True)`

Comment: If I could tell you, I would!  I'm not that familiar with DRF.  You might get better results if you create a new question specifically about *"how to avoid race conditions with DRF"*, and show the code for the vulnerable serializers.

Answer (score 0):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os

def task():
    print("Executing our Task on Process {}".format(os.getpid()))

def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    task1 = executor.submit(task)
    task2 = executor.submit(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```